# Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am having a JPQL query which has to fetch only two fields one integer and a list value. Here I had created a Dto and mentioned the fields that need to be fetched.

//all variables are defined

```
 query = new StringBuilder();
 query.append(ReposJPQL.GET_INCIDENTS);
 q = em.createQuery(query.toString());
 result = q.getResultList();
```

where query,

```
GET_INCIDENTS = "SELECT DISTINCT searchDto ("
            + "ih.Id,  ih.logs )"
            + "FROM Hdr ih left join ih.logs sl";
```

### searchDto

```
public class SearchDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer ID
    private List<IncidentStatusLogDto> statusLogs;

    public SearchDto () {
    }

    public SearchDto (Long incidentId, List<IncidentStatusLogDto> statusLogs) {
        super();
        this.incidentId = incidentId;
        this.statusLogs = statusLogs;
    }

}
```

### HDR Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TB_HDR")
public class IncidentHdr implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private Id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  mappedBy="incidentHdr")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Log> logs;

//getters and setters

}
```

Here I had added the constructor in searchDto as required, still it throws exception.

```
no appropriate constructor in class: SearchDto]
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.DetailedSemanticException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class SearchDto]. Expected arguments are: long, java.util.Collection
```

When I tried with only Id as value and removed the list it working.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors in the **SearchDTO** class:

1. Missing a semicolon in `private Integer ID` should be `private Integer ID;`
2. You are trying to set `this.incidentId = incidentId;` in the constructor but you don't have defined the variable.

As I don't know if you have missed it or if you want to replace it by the variable `ID` my proposal of solution is:

```
public class SearchDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer ID;
    private Long incidentId;
    private List<IncidentStatusLogDto> statusLogs;

    public SearchDto () {
    }

    public SearchDto (Long incidentId, List<IncidentStatusLogDto> statusLogs) {
        super();
        this.incidentId = incidentId;
        this.statusLogs = statusLogs;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting that typo errors. But my actual question is about a runtime error.